# failed to post data at local mongodb from node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This code is of the connect to the mongodb i can see in console that successfully connect to mongodb i cant create a new user by sending data in the request boby.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false"
    const connectToMongo = () => {
        mongoose.connect(mongoURI, () => {
            console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully");
        })
    }
    module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

This code is for authentication end point

```
const express =require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router = express.Router();
const user =  require('../models/User');

    router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
      res.send(req.body);
        const user = User(req.body);
        console.log(req.body);
        user.save;
    })

    
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Looks like you are sending a response before saving new user. You're also not calling the .save() method (should look like `user.save()` - furthermore, you'll need to await that save call.

Comment: Thank you its just connection string problem and user.save()

Answer (score 0):

Its just problem with the connection string and a typo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).